# compress video file before uploading to server

Tags: android, performance

I am trying to upload the video file to server , for small size video like 4 to 5 mb it works fine , but if when i am trying to upload the video more than 15 to 20 mb , it takes too much time for upload , that's why i want to compress the video , is there any library or tool available for compressing video before uploading to server.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are few approaches that you can take to upload larger size video on to the server:

1) You can make use of standard way of recording it across all mobiles which give you standard size:

```
    mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));  
    mediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(690000 );
```

2) Make use of ffmpeg or work around with it, it might help to compress video.
    https://github.com/halfninja/android-ffmpeg-x264

3) (Recommended) Compressing the video according to me will degrade the quality of video to far worse stage, so what the other work around and best which majorly used is:

Make a Byte array of the video
Make small Chunks of that byte array
Make a Web-service on Server reads this Chunk one by one, send it in queue.
Once received on server make a Video file out of it again.
Runs this Operation in Background async or as service anyways. So it doesnt effect foreground process. Once its done Just Notify!!

Hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

You can try use the FFMpeg library.

It's easy way to compress videos.

Can you check the site https://www.ffmpeg.org/ for more information, or post as comment what are you need to compress.

If you change CRF with the command -crf "15~25". It's a good compress video with good quality.